# How to filter out a long list of sites from Google search?

Tags: google-search

I have a list of sites I would like to permanently exclude from Google search results. These are the large family of sites plagiarizing (and some of them garbling with machine translation) Q&A from the StackExchange network, like `qaru.site`. I've created a filtering search engine in Chromium, with URL like `https://google.com/search?q=%s+-site:site1+-site:site2+-...+-site:siteN`, with some 30 sites to blacklist. Naturally, after I blacklisted one more site, Google started to complain:

> "site:qano.site" (and any subsequent words) was ignored because we limit queries to 32 words.

So some of these blacklisted domains aren't actually blacklisted.

I have tried using Chromium extensions for filtering search results, but these generally work on a higher level, only filtering the results page, often leaving me with almost empty page instead of presenting the pageful of more relevant results as does the `-site:domain.com` token in the search query.

So, how can I permanently have a blacklist for a potentially large set of sites? I'd prefer not to have to log in to Google for this.

Comment: _"tried using Chromium extensions...", "created a filtering search engine in Chromium...", "...prefer not to have to log in to Google..."_. I think you run out of choices. I believe your best bet is to create a custom search engine. If you want me to, I can turn this to an answer.

Comment: @marikamitsos Custom search engine seems to only allow to search in one specific site. It's not the same as search on the whole observable web, filtering out bad sites.

Comment: Key word being "seems". You can add many, many..., many...... more. There is a trick to exclude them as well. [See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAV5s.png). Have to go now. We can turn this to an answer if it suits you.

Comment: @marikamitsos OK, found it. Apparently, I have to specify any site to begin configuring my CSE, then I can delete it, having turned on the _"Search the entire web"_ option.

Comment: You do not have to delete the site as you mention in your answer. On the contrary, it helps if you keep it. In any case, I also posted my answer with additional info. _(You can now delete yours or not. I leave it to your discretion)_. :)

Comment: @marikamitsos how does it help? It biases search results if the site has any searchable info: see [Custom Search vs Google.com](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/70392?hl=en). This is contrary to my aim of having normal Google web search with filtering.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to user [marikamitsos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/117311/marikamitsos), I've found out that Google Custom Search Engines can work for the entire web.

To do this, I had to

1. Go to https://cse.google.com/cse/create/new
2. Add any site in the *"Sites to search"* field (I used `example.com`)
3. After creating the Custom Search Engine, go to its configuration
4. In the configuration, enable the *"Search the entire web"* option
5. Delete the site entry you used in step 2
6. In the *"Sites to search"* section of configuration, click *"Advanced"*
7. There, in the *"Sites to exclude"* section, you can exclude sites. If you have a list of sites to exclude, make sure they are each on a new line and paste the list in the text field in the *"Add"*→*"Exclude sites in bulk"* dialog
8. Press Save
9. Now that you have your Custom Search Engine, grab its URL from the *"Public URL"* section
10. To make a custom Chromium/Chrome search engine (to easily search from the address bar), you can use the URL you took in the previous step and appending `&q=%s` to it. Thus, my custom Chromium search engine URL looks like follows (with the ID replaced by a placeholder):

```
https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYYYY&q=%s
```

Answer (score 4):

*As mentioned in my [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/117311/marikamitsos) the way to **filter out a long list of sites from Google search** is by creating a Google Custom Search Engine (CSE). This allows you to have it customized with **up to 500 sites***.

#### How to create a Google Custom Search Engine (CSE) in 6 steps

**1. Go to** https://cse.google.com/cse/create/new
**2. Add any name** as your site in the *"Sites to search"* field (e.g. `mySearchSite.com`), give it a friendly name and click **`Create`**.

[image]

**3. After creating** your Custom Search Engine, click on the **`Control Panel`**. You land on the **`Basics`** tab.

[image]

**4. Copy** its URL from the *"Public URL"* section  and save it somewhere.

[image]

**5. Remain** on the **`Basics`** tab. Scroll down, enable the **`Search the entire web`** option and then click on the **`Advanced`** button.

[image]

**6. Under `Sites to exclude` click `Add`** and **`Exclude sites in bulk`**. You can add up to 500 sites, each on a new line. Press **`Save`**.

[image]

**You finished. Enjoy :)**
*Extra bonus: You can many CSE configured for different uses*.

---

#### How to use your CSE public URL

**1. As a bookmark** on any/all of your browsers for easy access.
**2. As your default** custom search engine (to easily search from the address bar of your browser) by appending `&q=%s` to it.
**3. Add it to your site** and monetize it's use.

Answer (score -1):

I did some research but couldn't find a way round the 32 word query limit for Google specifically. Apparently, according to this source from 2017, Yahoo search doesn't seem to have a word limit so you could try that instead.

https://www.quora.com/What-determines-the-32-word-limit-for-Google-searches