# Search engine uses wikipedia result as default?

Tags: search, wikipedia, search-engine

I tried searching for what this is called but couldn't find a result.

So when searching for anything on a search engine it will give you a list of results but on the right-hand side a box will show the wikipedia definition or entry about what you searched. For example in the image below I searched for bananas and on the right in the red box you will see what I am talking about.

My question is can this be removed completely, or can you choose a different site to get the information from? I have found that wikipedia is unreliable for many results and I would prefer not to see it.  I already use uBlacklist with Firefox and this does not remove it.

[image: Search result for bananas]

Comment: What search engine are you asking about?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions here [How to filter out a long list of sites from Google search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/134847)

Comment: I have tried all the major search engines, and I've tried the link.